# Need to locate Xpath using relative path with navigation from parent node

Tags: android, selenium, xpath, appium, android-uiautomator

I am using UIautomator to identify objects of a native mobile app. I am trying to locate Xpath for vehicle model field of given screenshot but that object has same class and package name as other 2 objects of same page.

So I am trying to write a relative path.I tried below path which is failing with unable to locate object error. How can I determine the correct xpath here?

I tried below which failed:

```
xpath="//android.widget.ScrollView/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.Spinner/android.widget.TextView[contains(text(),'86')]"
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot is way too tiny for me to make out detail information, but if you have highlighted the element you want, the properties appear to show a resource-id value.  That's all you need.

Comment: What is the exception are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

As per the snapshot of the *HTML* you have provided and your code trials the node **`android.widget.Spinner`** is **not the only child node** of it's parent node **`android.widget.LinearLayout`**. Hence you see the error.

### Solution

Change the *xpath* as :

```
"//android.widget.ScrollView/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout//android.widget.Spinner/android.widget.TextView[contains(text(),'86')]"
```

Comment: Tried above path but still no luck. still unable to locate object